# R data manipulations

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I would really appreciate some help...
I have distribution histograms of the height of things from different countries and different regions of each country (see table), and I need to do the following:

1. transform the histogram data back into "raw" data vectors (that is, replicate the *height*, *count* times). For example:
   England-north: 12,12,12,12,12,11,11,11,10,8
   England-south: 12,12,10,10,7,7,7,7,7
   and so on...
2. calculate the Wasserstein distance - `transport::wasserstein1d(vectorA, vectorB)` - between **each pair** of vectors.

| Country | Region | Height | Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| England | north | 12 | 5 |
| England | north | 11 | 3 |
| England | north | 10 | 1 |
| England | north | 8 | 1 |
| England | south | 12 | 2 |
| England | south | 10 | 2 |
| England | south | 7 | 5 |
| France | East | 11 | 3 |
| France | East | 10 | 1 |
| France | East | 8 | 1 |
| France | South | 12 | 2 |
| France | South | 11 | 3 |
| France | South | 10 | 1 |

Comment: Do you need the results of 1) as an intermediary step? If so, in what format?

Comment: Do you always have exactly 2 regions for each country and you want `transport::wasserstein1d(region1, region2)` ?

Comment: @ktiu: no, I don't need the intermediary results.  Ronak: no, I actually have 15 countries and 8 regions (exactly) per country. Also, I want to to compare between different regions from different countries (all vs. all).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my approach to generating a distance matrix:

```
library(dplyr)

your_data %>%
  mutate(full_region = paste(Country, Region)) %>%
  group_by(full_region) %>%
  summarize(points = list(rep(Height, Count))) %>%
  (\(df) matrix(df$points, dimnames = list(df$full_region))) %>%
  usedist::dist_make(\(a, b) transport::wasserstein1d(a[[1]], b[[1]]))
```

Returns:

```
              England north England south France East
England south     2.3222222                          
France East       0.9000000     1.8666667            
France South      0.4000000     2.3888889   0.9666667
```

Data used:

```
your_data <- structure(list(Country = c("England", "England", "England", "England", "England", "England", "England", "France", "France", "France", "France", "France", "France"), Region = c("north", "north", "north", "north", "south", "south", "south", "East", "East", "East", "South", "South", "South"), Height = c(12L, 11L, 10L, 8L, 12L, 10L, 7L, 11L, 10L, 8L, 12L, 11L, 10L), Count = c(5L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L)), row.names = c(NA, -13L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Nice! However I get an "unexpected input" error message regarding the "\" symbol in the line:                                      
  (\(df) matrix...

Comment: You can replace `\(df)` with `function(df)` or upgrade to the latest version of R (4.1)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way using `combn` -

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  uncount(Count) %>%
  split(.[c('Country', 'Region')]) %>%
  Filter(nrow, .) -> list_df

do.call(rbind, combn(seq_along(list_df), 2, function(x) {
  data.frame(region1 = paste0(list_df[[x[1]]]$Country[1],list_df[[x[1]]]$Region[1]), 
             region2 = paste0(list_df[[x[2]]]$Country[1],list_df[[x[2]]]$Region[1]),
              result = transport::wasserstein1d(list_df[[x[1]]]$Height, 
                                                list_df[[x[2]]]$Height))
}, simplify = FALSE))

#       region1      region2 result
#1   FranceEast Englandnorth  0.900
#2   FranceEast Englandsouth  1.867
#3   FranceEast  FranceSouth  0.967
#4 Englandnorth Englandsouth  2.322
#5 Englandnorth  FranceSouth  0.400
#6 Englandsouth  FranceSouth  2.389
```

Comment: Thank you! One more question: as it is now, the output only appears in the console - how do I send it to a new, named dataframe to be saved?

Comment: Just assign it to a new variable name. `....simplify = FALSE)) -> result`. and `result` will have the output.